# How to fix MPMoviePlayerController iO7 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using https://github.com/MarcosSTM/LBYouTubeView for playing you tube video..

In that after extracting video URL. I am playing youtube video using MPMoviePlayerController as I want to play the video within the frame not in full screen mode automatically.

My code is below.

MPMoviePlayerController *movieController; at view controller .h file

```
-(void)youTubePlayerViewController:(LBYouTubePlayerViewController *)controller didSuccessfullyExtractYouTubeURL:(NSURL *)videoURL
{


    if ([delegate_LbYouTube respondsToSelector:@selector(youTubePlayerViewController:didSuccessfullyExtractYouTubeURL:)])
{
    [delegate_LbYouTube youTubePlayerViewController:controller didSuccessfullyExtractYouTubeURL:youvideoURL];
}

controller.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
controller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
controller.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,102, 320, 315);

controller.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime=[popular.startStr doubleValue];
controller.moviePlayer.endPlaybackTime=[popular.endStr doubleValue];
 controller.moviePlayer.contentURL = youvideoURL;
[controller.moviePlayer play];

[self.view addSubview:controller.moviePlayer.view];

}

-(void)youTubePlayerViewController:(LBYouTubePlayerViewController *)controller failedExtractingYouTubeURLWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"URL extracting failed with error: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Everything works fine. Sometimes the same video is running and sometimes getting below error..

_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
kind = 1;
new = 2;
old = 0;
}

I googled a lot and modified my code as per answers posted in similar questions.But could not rectify the issue...

Please suggest how can I fix this error..Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: LBYouTubePlayerViewController (subclassed version of MPMoviePlayerViewController) has a member of type MPMoviePlayerController already - no need to instantiate another one. In fact, it could be rather harmful to do so.

Comment: no need to instantiate another one means.. do not want to instantiate the MPMOviePlayerController... if i remove that code.. then where i have to set frame @Till

Comment: If i do not allocate MPMOviePlayerController then the video not at all playing.. even some times also @Till

Comment: If I was you, I would use a standard `UIViewController` subclass and copy the parts from `LBYouTubePlayerViewController` that you really need and add them to your standard `UIViewController`. Your symptoms (sometimes it works fine, sometimes it does not) sound a lot like a race condition. Such race condition might be introduced by you using a  MPMoviePlayerViewController but adding a new player instance and using your own view - again, I would really not recommend doing that.